# Doing a PowerShell Remote Session Using Invoke-Command To No Effect

Tags: powershell, deployment, scripting, devops, powershell-remoting

In PowerShell, I'm doing a remote session to a server. I want to add files to the remote server and have them actually live there. When running the following code, nothing gets added to the server. Why is this and what can be done to actually add files to the server?

```
Enable-PSRemoting -Force

$SomeComputer= "some-server.com"
$SomeUsername = "some-username"
$SomePassword =  ConvertTo-SecureString "some-password" -AsPlainText -Force

$SomeCredentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($SomeUsername, $SomePassword)
$SomeSession = New-PSSession -ComputerName $SomeComputer -Credential $SomeCredentials

Invoke-Command -Session $SomeSession -ScriptBlock {
    New-Item -Path "SomeFile.txt" -ItemType File
}
```

Comment: If you do `Invoke-Commad`, complete with computername and credentials, you should not first enter a session to that computer. If you use `Enter-PSSession`, you are starting an interactive session with that remote computer, so from then on you are logged in there so to speak and can run the `New-Item` cmdlet as if it is on your local machine. Also, make sure you use a complete path to the new `somefile.txt` you are creating.

Comment: I agree with Theo here, I believe what you want is `New-PSSession`, then you reference that instance.

Comment: I've replaced the Enter-PSSession with New-PSSession and am using it in the Invoke-Command now. Still no luck. Also thanks for the reminder of the complete path.

Comment: What if you try using an absolute path? Are you getting any error from invoke command?

Comment: Even with an absolute path like "C:\stuff0\stuff1\stuff2\SomeFile.txt", it doesn't work out. No errors from the invoke command. I've looked up and down and scoured the internet to no avail.